# How to solve $\sin\theta +\sin3\theta =0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Solve the equation by first using a Sum-to-Product Formula.
>
> $$\sin\theta +\sin3\theta =0$$

Steps I took:

$$\begin{align}0&=2\sin\frac { \theta +3\theta  }{ 2 } \cos\frac { \theta -3\theta  }{ 2 }\\
0&=2\sin\frac { 4\theta  }{ 2 } \cos\frac { -2\theta  }{ 2 } \\
0&=2\sin2\theta \cos(-\theta)\\
0&=2\sin2\theta \cos\theta\\
0&=2(2\sin\theta \cos\theta )\cos\theta\\
0&=4\sin\theta \cos^2\theta \\
0&=4\sin\theta \frac { 1+\cos2\theta  }{ 2 } \\
0&=4\sin\theta \frac { 1+1-2\sin^2\theta  }{ 2 } \\
0&=4\sin\theta \frac { 2-2\sin^{ 2 }\theta  }{ 2 } \\
0&=\frac { 8\sin\theta -8\sin^{ 2 }\theta  }{ 2 }\end{align}$$

Comment: I think you can stop at $4\sin\theta\cos^2\theta=0$

Comment: @cand Even earlier. At $2\sin(2\theta)\cos\theta = 0$.

Comment: I think you last step is wrong.

Comment: you could stop at your fourth step $0=2\sin 2 \theta \cos \theta .$ that tells you, either $\sin 2 \theta = 0$ or $\cos \theta = 0.$ these have solutions $2\theta = n\pi$ and $\theta = n\pi + \pi/2$ where $n$ is an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I see, you didn't make any mistake in your calculation. You did, however, overcomplicate things.

For one, if $2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = 0$, you can get rid of the $2$ and just write $\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = 0$.

The main mistake you made, however, was when you got to $2\sin(2\theta)\cos\theta$. From there on, you should ask yourself this:

> If $a\cdot b = 0$, what can I say about $a$ and $b$?

---

*An edit answering your question if you were completely wrong:*

No, you were not wrong. The only place you were wrong is when you rewrote

$$4\sin(\theta)\frac{2-2\sin^2\theta}{2}$$

Into $$\frac{8\sin\theta - 8\sin^2\theta}{2}.$$

There is a small mistake here. Other than that, you are correct, but truly horribly inefficient.

For example, in row $6$, you wrote $4\sin\theta \cos^2\theta = 0$, then you took another $4$ rows before you got to $4\sin(\theta)\frac{2-2\sin^2\theta}{2} = 0$, when, in fact, you could just replace $\cos^2\theta$ with $1-\sin^2\theta$ and get the same result.

Comment: one of them must be $0$

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Meaning that, if you apply this to $2\sin(2\theta)\cos(\theta) = 0$, you get...?

Comment: set each term to $0$?

Comment: Well, either $\cos(\theta)=0$ (this will give you one part of the solutions) or $\sin(2\theta) = 0$ (the other part).

Comment: Was the way I was going completely wrong? (not counting inefficiency)

Comment: @Cherry_Developer See the edit to my answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was busy in the afternoon.

Answer (score 4):

As $\sin(-\theta)=-\sin\theta,$

$$\sin3\theta=-\sin\theta=\sin(-\theta)$$

$$3\theta=m\pi+(-1)^m(-\theta)$$ where $m$ is any integer

Check if $m$ is even $(=2r)$(say) and $m$ is odd $(=2r+1)$(say) one by one

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin(\theta) + \sin(3\theta) = 0$$

Using sum-to-product,

$$2\sin\left(\frac{\theta+3\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta - 3\theta}{2}\right) = 0$$

$$2\sin(2\theta)\cos(-\theta) = 0$$

$$2\sin(\theta+\theta)\cos(-\theta)= 0$$

Using either the double angle or sum-difference formulas,

$$4\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\cos(-\theta) = 0$$

By the definition of cosine and getting rid of the 4,

$$\sin(\theta)\cos^2(\theta) = 0$$

Using co-function identities,

$$\tag{1}\sin(\theta)\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta) = 0 $$

We know that $\sin$ is zero at $k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ so,

$$\theta = k\pi$$ in which case the left-hand $\sin$ in (1) is 0 or, $$\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$$ in which case the right-hand $\sin$ in (1) is zero.